# Simple list manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I have two lists: {1,2,3} and {a,b,c} and I want this result: {{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}}. What is the right command? How does one call such an operation?

Comment: [`Transpose[{{1,2,3},{a,b,c}}]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

Comment: Look up `Transpose[]`. (I am quite sure this is a dupe.)

Comment: `MapThread[List, {{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}]`

Comment: I've always used `Thread[{{1,2,3},{a,b,c}}]` rather than `Transpose`.

Comment: @wxffles I use `Thread` a lot too.  It is worth comparing performance between the two for any given problem and *Mathematica* revision, as there have been some significant differences.